# Authentication with Facebook on mobile and Django

Tags: facebook, cordova, django-authentication

I am developing a Facebook application for mobile platforms. The mobile part is being developed with PhoneGap and the server side is Python / Django.

The mobile app should be able to query Facebook API directly. Server should be able to query Facebook API on the users' behalf too. Thus the user should be authenticated both with Facebook and on the server (Django), and the server should have the user's Facebook authentication token.

What would be the best flow for authenticating the user on both sides? Is it reasonable to authenticate on Facebook via mobile app, then send the token to the server and create a django session on the server?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement: jQueryMobile app with Ruby On Rails backend.  In my case, I implemented the Facebook authentication on the backend using omniauth.  The backend retrieves the Facebook access token and passes it to the jQueryMobile frontend.  The frontend then uses JSONP to retrieve the user's friend list.  The advantage of this approach is that there is a single point of authentication -- Facebook auth at the backend.

You can find a demo of my app and the full source code at http://csgrad.blogspot.com/2011/07/jquerymobile-app-with-facebook.html